# Data Validation - Update Dynamically Based on Value in Table

Tags: excel

I have two tabs on my workbook, the first contains a table detailing project names, stages and tasks, which will be updated regularly by the users :

```
Project Name    Project Stage    Project Task    
------------------------------------------------------
Project 1       Design           First stage of design
Project 1       Design           Second stage of design
Project 1       Build            First stage of build
Project 1       Test             First stage of test
Project 2       Design           First stage of design
Project 2       Design           Second stage of design
Project 3       Design           Second stage of design
```

On my 2nd tab, I want to use data validation lists which will be used to display an individual view of each task for each stage of the project :

```
Project Name   |  *Validation list from column A in tab1
Project Stage  |  *Validation list based on the value in Project Name field
Project Task   |  *Validation list based on the value in Project Name AND Project Stage fields
```

I have set up the Project Name list to read from the table in Tab1. I'd like the list options for Project Stage in Tab 2 to update based on the value selected in Project Name.

I have read a few guides on here and elsewhere that all seem to involve creating several named tables on a separate tab and using INDIRECT. I'd ideally like to avoid creating any dummy tables as this will become difficult to maintain when the file is handed over to the users.

Is there away to configure the Project Stage dropdown to dynamically update based on the selection in Project Name, only showing the stages that are listed in Tab1 for that particular Project.

Hope I have articulated this sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will only work if your Project Names are all grouped together, i.e. you won't have a mash-up of `Project 1 | Project 3 | Project 1 | Project 5 | Project 3 | ...` in column A.

I'm also assuming that your data is stored in cells `A1:C8`:

[image]

As per my understanding, you would like to have a dynamic drop-down list (Validation list) that will show:

- `B2:B5` range for `Project 1`,
- `B6:B7` range  for `Project 2`,
- `B8:B8` range for `Project 3`.

In order to achieve that, we need to use `MATCH` formula to find the first occurrence of your chosen Project Name and combine it with `LOOKUP` to find its last occurrence. Create a Named Range ("ProjectName") and use the following formula (I'm assuming that the Project Name is specified in cell F2):

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(Sheet1!$F$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8,0)-1,1,LOOKUP(Sheet1!$F$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8))-MATCH(Sheet1!$F$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8,0)+1,1)
```

Here's how the final result will look like after using "ProjectName" in the Validation List:

[image]